# AWS transcribe speaker diarization, segments single speaker sentences into multiple different speakers

Tags: amazon-web-services, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, amazon-transcribe

A bit of context, we have been using AWS Transcribe for English transcription since last one year. When the number of speakers is unknown, transcribe asks you to provide max number of speakers, by default we are passing 5.

> Since last month we observed that the ability to differentiate between speakers has gone down drastically. Spoken words from a single speaker gets broken into multiple speaker sentences. Even when there are only 2 speakers.

Any pointers would be helpful.